# ElementAPI endpoint routing syntax for multi-level structure

Tags: routing, plugin-elementapi

Would like to be able to handle requests for structured requests so that it may be handled in one endpoint

```
    about.json
    about/the-team.json
    about/contact/london.json
```

Presumably a form of regex would be required for this to work?
Contemplating:

```
    pages/about.json
    pages/about/the-team.json
    pages/about/contact/london.json
```

All though how would you prepare a check for 'pages' as your first node?

Currently have this but not fees able.

```
   '<slug:{slug}>*.json' => function($slug) {
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a simple solution set the criteria to uri and you just pass the endpoint as is as a catch all.

```
$normal =  preg_replace('/.json/', '', craft()->request->path);
return [
        'endpoints' => [
            craft()->request->path => [
                'elementType' => 'Entry',
                'criteria' => ['uri' => $normal],
                'first' => true,
                'transformer' => new DetailTransformer(),
            ],
        ]
    ];
```